# golang и mssql ошибка "mssql: Cannot convert a char value to money. The char value has incorrect syntax."

Tags: sql, sql-server, golang

Есть старая база MSSQL и мне нужно наладить с ней контакт. Само подключение к ней происходит без проблем но с запросами происходит какая то беда. 
Есть таблица [Сотрудники] с полями:
`id, Name, E-mail` и к примеру мне нужно вытянуть имя зная только почту.
Вот так выглядит мой метод:

```
func (w *Wrapper) GetAuthorInIntexOrder(email string) (string) {
    row := IntexDB.QueryRow("SELECT Name FROM [Сотрудники] WHERE [E-mail] = $1", email)

    var name string
    err := row.Scan(
        &name,
    )

    if err != nil {
        log.Warn("[database]GetAuthorInIntexOrder->row.Scan: ", err.Error())
        return ""
    }
    return name
}
```

В ответ я получаю ошибку: `"[database]GetAuthorInIntexOrder->row.Scan: mssql: Cannot convert a char value to money. The char value has incorrect syntax."` У Name тип nvarchar и я не понимаю почему вообще происходит конвертация в money, это же просто строка. Я пользуюсь драйвером `github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb`. Интересно что если убрать условие WHERE то запрос выполнится и я получу 1й элемент в таблице. Как думаете в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Есть сомнение, что запрос в QueryRow записан правильно. $1 - это значение типа `money`

Comment: А с чего Вы решили, что проблема именно с конвертацией Name? Может, это с подстановкой $1 грабли? На всякий случай - не поленитесь в тексте запроса обрамить Name квадратными скобками, а $1 одинарными кавычками... сперва - по отдельности.

Comment: Да проблема оказалось в подстановке $1. Я подставил вместо $1 реальную почту (SELECT [Name] FROM [Сотрудники] WHERE [E-mail] = 'test@test.ru') и запрос отработал. Я не могу обернуть одинарными кавычками $1 потому что тогда это не будет являться подстановкой. Не могу понять как мне правильно передать данные.

Comment: *Я не могу обернуть одинарными кавычками $1 потому что тогда это не будет являться подстановкой.* ??? А Вы просто попробуйте... `row := IntexDB.QueryRow("SELECT Name FROM [Сотрудники] WHERE [E-mail] = '$1' ", email)`

Comment: `... или `row := IntexDB.QueryRow("SELECT Name FROM [Сотрудники] WHERE [E-mail] = '?' ", email)`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Уверен - в запрос не попадает значение переменной email, а передается значение $1 типа `money`, поэтому при попытке преобразования значения из столбца `[E-mail]` получаете ошибку.

Попробуйте:

```
row := IntexDB.QueryRow("SELECT Name FROM [Сотрудники] WHERE [E-mail] = @p1", email)
```

Comment: Ваш вариант не подходит, результат - ошибка: `mssql: Incorrect syntax near '?'.`

Comment: Но вот такой вариант работает: `IntexDB.QueryRow("SELECT [Name] FROM [Сотрудники] WHERE [E-mail] = '" + email + "'")`

Comment: Попробуйте еще с `@p1`

Comment: Спасибо большое! Вариант с @p1 сработал.